# Using Guava Cache inside Log4J custom appender

Tags: caching, log4j, guava

I have a Log4j custom appender and is working well.  I need to modify its behavior such that it will only log based on a value the code obtains from calling a restFul service.  Since the value changes once in a while, I want to cache it so I don't have to reach across the wire every time a log event comes in.   I tried putting Guava cache but got the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" 
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: 
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive load of

I guess this makes sense since this is every LogEvent.

What is the right mechanism to have some kind of cacheing mechanism that's
shared across all Log4j threads?

thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell from this description. You could use a `ThreadLocal` flag to know if you are recursing.

Comment: Do you have the rest of the error statement? That might help someone attempting to answer.